# Фикс калькулятора

Tags: javascript

```js
let persons = document.getElementsByClassName('counter-block-input')[0],
  restDays = document.getElementsByClassName('counter-block-input')[1],
  place = document.getElementById('select'),
  totalValue = document.getElementById('total'),
  personsSum = 0,
  daysSum = 0,
  total = 0;

totalValue.innerHTML = 0;

persons.addEventListener('change', function() {
  personsSum = +this.value;
  total = (daysSum + personsSum) * 4000;
  if (restDays.value === '') {
    totalValue.innerHTML = 0;
  } else {
    totalValue.innerHTML = total;
  }
});

restDays.addEventListener('change', function() {
  daysSum = +this.value;
  total = (daysSum + personsSum) * 4000;
  if (persons.value === '') {
    totalValue.innerHTML = 0;
  } else {
    totalValue.innerHTML = total;
  }
});

place.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (restDays.value === '' || persons.value === '') {
    totalValue.innerHTML = 0;
  } else {
    totalValue.innerHTML = total * this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="counter" id="price">
  <div class="counter-title">Рассчитайте стоимость вашего отдыха
  </div>
  <div class="counter-block">
    <div class="counter-block-option">Количество людей</div>
    <input type="number" min="1" step="1" class="counter-block-input">
  </div>
  <div class="counter-block">
    <div class="counter-block-option">На сколько дней</div>
    <input type="number" min="1" step="1" class="counter-block-input">
  </div>
  <div class="counter-block">
    <div class="counter-block-option">Выберете базу</div>
    <select name="place" id="select">
      <option id="mumbai" value="1">Индия, Мумбай</option>
      <option id="kerala" value="1.5">Индия, Керала</option>
      <option id="varanasi" value="1.8">Индия, Варанаси</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="counter-total">
    Общая сумма<br>
    <span id="total">20456</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Если ввести 2 числа и потом очистить один инпут, калькулятор все равно рассчитывает стоимость.
Понимаю, нужно как-то проверку переписать, но не понимаю как.

Comment: Вам нужно + заменить на *. Не нужно складывать людей с днями.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло